# Azimuth and Altitude of a Meteor Shower

Tags: altitude, meteorites, meteoroid, meteors

What is a reliable source to understand the Azimuth and Altitude of a meteor shower at a specific geographic location at an instant of time for observation?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "undertand", but if you just want to know where they are, many planetarium apps will display them along with their alt/az coordinates.  Stellarium is one.

Comment: Wikipedia has a good article on meteor showers. If it doesn't help, please clarify your question.

Comment: The meteors in a shower can be seen in all parts of the sky, so the meteors themselves have no azimuth/altitude. However, they appear to radiate from a single point in the sky (the radiant point) which has a specific azimuth/altitude. Paradoxically, the radiant point is the only place in the sky you will NOT see a meteor steak by.